# Any way to change the sampling frequency of a WAV (or MP3) in Android or just Java?

Tags: java, android, wav, frequency, sampling

I'm trying to get files played through a mono (SCO) BT headset in Android. The files have to have an 8000 Hz frequency, but the ones I have are 44100 Hz. The files are MP3s, but I've already created code to convert them to WAVs, since I know that Android doesn't handle MP3s natively.

This has to be done on the device at execution time,so can anyone offer any suggestions?

I should mention that I don't care what format the files end up in, as long as they can be played back using MediaPlayer.

Comment: As I understand it, resampling is an intensive process if you want it to sound decent.  On my desktop, it takes several seconds of processing time to do this conversion using dedicated software, and it is certainly more powerful than this device.  Are you willing to wait a long time for this conversion process (MP3 > WAV > Resample), when the quality of the audio will be horrible to listen to?

Comment: In my understanding, MediaPlayer should be able to handle 44100 Hz. Is there a reason for your 8000 Hz limitation? Perhaps it could help us to lead you to the most proper solution. Also, which API versions are you targeting?

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, I need it to stream to a mono BT headset, and it only works perfectly with a mono 8000Hz stream.

Answer (score 0):

44100/8000=5.5125
so you can try to take 5.5125 samples and calculate the average value and so reduce the sample rate

I think this should work although Im sure the result will be noisy but ist worth trying

you can also take  every 5.5125  sample
maybe this can help you 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downsampling

Comment: I understand what you mean in principle, but how do I do it on Android (Java) if all I have is the original MP3/WAV file?

Comment: you can load the wav in a buffer hope this helps http://mindtherobot.com/blog/580/android-audio-play-a-wav-file-on-an-audiotrack/

Comment: can you please publish the code for converting mp3 to wav? thanks :)

Comment: You cannot simply do that. There will be anti-aliasing, which will distort the audio. You will have to apply a low pass filter first.